# Selenium logs out automatically

Tags: selenium, testng

I am working on VCM and have created some test script using Selenium and TestNG (not using webdriver).

The problem is that as soon as it logins it automatically logs-out showing the error that the link was not found. If individual run the scripts run perfectly but when running the Suite it always fails showing above mentioned error.

Here's my code for reference:

```
    @BeforeTest
public void setup()
{
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://BaseURL/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowMaximize();
}
@AfterTest
public void teardown()
{
    this.selenium.close();
}

@Test public void testTC_07() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("http://BaseWebsite");
    selenium.type("name=j_username", "UserId");
    selenium.type("name=j_password", "PassWord");
    selenium.click("id=login-button");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    selenium.click("id=href_Menus");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    selenium.click("link=TestContents");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    selenium.click("link=Test");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    selenium.click("link=Test_title");
    selenium.waitForPopUp("Pop Up Window", "60000");
    selenium.selectWindow("null");
    verifyEquals(selenium.getTitle(), "Test_Title Properties Window");
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Title"));
    selenium.type("id=textbox", "");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    selenium.click("id=doOK");
    String title= selenium.getTitle();

    if(title!="Window Title"){
        selenium.close();
        selenium.selectWindow("null");
        selenium.click("link=Logout");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
        }

    else{
        TC_07.fail(null);
        this.selenium.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: Does every test have the same username and password when logging in? Is there some functionality which kicks out the user if another user tries to log in?

Comment: @PavelJanicek:thnks... All test cases have same userid & password, also there is no such functionality I have checked that..

Comment: :( My guess is, that the page looks differently if you log in, then open new window (session is stored nowadays) and try to log in again. Because there should be nothing wrong...

Comment: is it possible that Selenium is too fast for some Ajax actions in behind? That was a common error for me in those days- Whay don't you use WebDriver instead?